# conversion failed when converting datee and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, date, type-conversion

I have this line that is causing the error. The pDOB field is a date datatype. And I got error updating.

strQuery += "pDOB = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pDOB"].ToString() + "',";

[image]

[image]

Error following comment code

[image]

```
private void LoadPatientRecords()
{

    //retrieve connection information info from App.config
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
    //STEP 1: Create connection
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    //STEP 2: Create command
    string strCommandText = "SELECT pat.patientid, pFirstName, pLastName, pContact, pAddress, pCity, pZip, pNationality, pRace, pIC, pGender, convert(varchar, pDOB, 103) AS pDOB, pBloodType, pEmail, pUsername, pPassword, rf.rfIdentification FROM Patient as Pat";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN RFID as rf on pat.patientid = rf.patientid";

    PatientAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

    //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
    // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
    //SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(PatientAdapter);
    // Empty Employee Table first
    Patient.Clear();
    // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
    // using SELECT statement
    PatientAdapter.Fill(Patient);

    // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
    if (Patient.Rows.Count > 0)
        grdPatient.DataSource = Patient;
}


private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strQuery = string.Empty;
        string strQuery2 = string.Empty;
        DataTable dtChanges;
        //
        // Get the Updated DataTable back from the DataGridView
        DataTable dtAppointment = (DataTable)grdPatient.DataSource;
        //
        // Get the Connection string from App.config.
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();
        //
        // Get the Modified Rows by filtering on their RowState
        dtChanges = dtAppointment.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
        if (dtChanges != null)
        {
            //
            // Form the UPDATE Query to Update the Rows.
            objConn.Open();
            objCmd.Connection = objConn;
            for (int i = 0; i < dtChanges.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                strQuery = "UPDATE PATIENT SET ";
                strQuery += "pFirstName = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pFirstName"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pLastName = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pLastName"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pContact = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pContact"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pAddress = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pAddress"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pCity = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pCity"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pZip = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pZip"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pNationality = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pNationality"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pRace = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pRace"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pIC = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pIC"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pGender = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pGender"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pDOB = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pDOB"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pBloodType = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pBloodType"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pEmail = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pEmail"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pUsername = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pUsername"].ToString() + "',";
                strQuery += "pPassword = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pPassword"].ToString() + "'";
                strQuery += "WHERE patientID = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["patientID"].ToString() + "'";

                //strQuery2 = "UPDATE APPOINTMENT SET ";
                //strQuery2 += "pFirstName = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pFirstName"].ToString() + "'";
                //strQuery2 += "WHERE appointmentID = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["appointmentID"].ToString() + "'";

                //
                // Execute the Update Query.
                objCmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            objConn.Close();
            dtChanges = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No update to change");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch, looks like medical software.. I'd consider using parameterised queries instead of building SQL strings. Read up on SQL injection - your solution looks vulnerable to it. Additionally, building up SQL strings can be a pain when it comes to interpreting dates etc - and you have fallen foul of that issue

Comment: Erm its ok, it only for a school project. I wan to use this method, how to convert my date to update properly for that line of pDOB? @Charleh

Comment: School is meant to teach you. Don't let it teach you to write horrible code like that. Use parameters. It may even be the source of your problem.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yes young padawan, you must learn the ways of the Force or you may fall foul to the dark side. But on a serious note - read up, you would only need to change a few lines of code to get this parameterised. It would be much more secure and much more robust. Nobody wants a brittle solution - even if it's a school project. The better you write your software the less headache you will have updating and maintaining it, and the less people you will get saying "It broke..."

Comment: Basically, all it might take to break it if you did format the string may be someone changing the SQL servers language setting. You can't really be guaranteed anything with date strings - my advice is to try and avoid them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next code:
  strQuery += "pDOB = '" + DateTime.Parse(dtChanges.Rows[i]["pDOB"].ToString()).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "', ";

instead of :
  strQuery += "pDOB = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pDOB"].ToString()) + "', ";

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments @Benny Emmers see Above image

Comment: Why `en-US`? Maybe `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: What kind of value contains the dtChanges.Rows[i]["pDOB"] ? I thought it would be a datetime. The datetime contains a ToString with two parameters The reason I want to use en-us is that internal sql server uses this. Can you try without the second parameter ?

Comment: U mean like this? See above image error. the pDOB is a date type not a date time type @Benny Emmers

Comment: @Jordjmax : an date object does not exist in .Net. Even if an object contains only a date it is still a datetime. Can you tell me the type of this object (use dtChanges.Rows[i]["pDOB"].DataType) ?

Comment: See second image for the datatype. I also added codes for the loading of gridview. And hey I found out that for etc, if i change from 15/04/1997 to 12/04/1997 for the second row, it updates sucessfully. That means the first column for the date must be 12 or lesser, that means the first column is the month. But I want it to be dd/mm/yyyy. @Benny Emmers

Comment: strQuery += "pDOB = '" + DateTime.Parse(dtChanges.Rows[i]["pDOB"].ToString()).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' "; => This works But pay attention to the remarks of the people I hope that your code is just for beginning to learn C#

Comment: Ok thanks. But I got incorrect syntax, see image 3. @Benny Emmers

Comment: Oh wait i forgot to put comma. @Benny Emmers

Comment: You must add a comma to the last part of the concatenation => strQuery += "pDOB = '" + DateTime.Parse(dtChanges.Rows[i]["pDOB"].ToString()).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "', ";

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Do u wanna put your comment in the answer so i can tick you? @Benny Emmers

Comment: I have done that. Thanks for ticking me. Good luck with learning C#